# Laplace transform and Fourier transform of kernel

Tags: probability-theory, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Suppose $p_t(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$ is the Gaussian density. $p_t(x)$ is also the Green kernel of the heat equation in 1D: $(\partial_t-\frac12\Delta)u=0$. The Fourier transform of $p_t(x)$ is $\hat p_t(\xi)=e^{-\frac{t}2|\xi|^2}$. Then the Laplace transform at 1 has the special bound
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}|\hat p_t(\xi)|^2dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}e^{-t|\xi|^2}dt\lesssim \frac1{1+|\xi|^2}. $$
In this bound, we see that this integration decay as $|\xi|^{-2}$ when $|\xi|\to\infty$. Note also that the Laplace transform is closely related to resolvent of the operator $\Delta$.

Suppose now that we replace $\Delta$ by a "nice" (symmetric) operator $A$ with symbol $\psi(\xi)$. What are the characteristics of $A$ so that we have a similar bound
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}|e^{-t\psi(\xi)}|^2dt\lesssim \frac1{1+|\xi|^a} $$
for some $\lambda>0$ and $a>0$. Is there a method to identify the decay rate $a$?

PS: I know this is probably well known in semigroup theory, but I couldn't find any exact reference.

Comment: What about $\alpha$-stable processes?

Comment: I probably thought too much. Suppose that $\psi$ is real and positive. Then the same estimate yields $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t} e^{-t\psi(\xi)}dt\lesssim \frac1{1+\psi(\xi)}.$$ I suppose $\alpha$-stable process is the case $\psi(\xi)=|\xi|^\alpha$. So this yields the decay rate as $(1+|\xi|^\alpha)^{-1}$.

In my earlier thought, I also consider the case $G_t(x)=1_{\{|x|<t\}}$, which is the kernel of the wave equation in 1D. This kernel also enjoys the decay rate as the heat kernel in 1D. I am not sure exactly what characteristics leads to the same decay rate.

Comment: I see. Would it be of interest for you to express the decay in terms of existence of moments of the corresponding Lévy measure?